# Bootstrap Modal Instead of Javascript Alert Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootbox

I am learner in JavaScript. I need a bootstrap modal instead of a alert inside a java script function. I did some changes, but i couldn't find the right solution. Please check my code and provide me with a solution. Thanks in advance.

```
<a id="deleteButton" onClick="delete_Vehicle()" class="alert" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">
<script>
function delete_Vehicle() {
    if (confirm('Do you want to delete the selected VEHICLE?')){
        DeleteDevice();
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the bootstrap modal alert function i am working on

```
$(document).on('click', '.alert', function(e) {
bootbox.confirm("Really delete this item?", function(result) {
    if(result !== true){
       e.preventDefault(); 
    }
});
```

});

In the popup if the ok button is clicked and  confirmed to delete, this function should get executed 
  **DeleteDevice();**

Comment: You mean like this? `if(result !== true){ e.preventDefault(); } else { DeleteDevice(); }`

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/L3ddq/1/

Comment: Bootstrap modals don't block, so putting e.preventDefault() in the callback isn't going to work as you think it should.

Answer (score 0):

The `result` callback argument determines whether user confirmed the action or not, so you should check if it's true and then call `DeleteDevice()`.

```
bootbox.confirm("Really delete this item?", function(result) {
  if (result === true) {
    DeleteDevice();
  }
});
```